# error regarding express app deployment on vercel

Tags: mongodb, express, deployment, vercel, web-development-server

i deployed an express app on vercel repo[text](https://github.com/himanshukandari14/campus.git) which has connection to mongoDB when i m opening deployed site its  correctly rendering register and lo9gin page but when i am tring to craete an account or logging in basically when i am trying to establish a connection with database it showing this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYFhz.png) and when i cheked logs its showing me this

Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option: useNewUrlParser has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useUnifiedTopology is a deprecated option: useUnifiedTopology has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version
Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017","reason":{"errorType":"MongooseServerSelectionError","errorMessage":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017","message":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017","reason":{"type":"Unknown","servers":{},"stale":false,"compatible":true,"heartbeatFrequencyMS":10000,"localThresholdMS":15,"setName":null,"maxElectionId":null,"maxSetVersion":null,"commonWireVersion":0,"logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes":null},"stack":["MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017","    at _handleConnectionErrors (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:809:11)","    at NativeConnection.openUri (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:784:11)","    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)","    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)","    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)","    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017","    at process. (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1276:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:529:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)","    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)","    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)","    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)"]}
Unhandled rejection: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
at _handleConnectionErrors (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:809:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:784:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError

i tried to deploy an express app on vercel

Comment: Hi, please read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you